# Why does the p4 plugin fail after the first check-out?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

**Questions**

1) Why does the p4 plugin fail with the error shown below after the first check-out?

2) What is the correct syntax for the addition of optional parameters, such as workspace behaviour?

**Background**

I have a new Jenkins installation on a clean Windows server. I'm trying to configure a new pipeline job which does nothing more than check out code from a perforce repo. using the p4 plug-in. I've spent several days getting almost nowhere and I'm now out of ideas short of writing a script that does the same thing and running that. Here's what I currently have in my groovy script:

```
stage 'A'
node{
    p4sync charset: 'none', credential: '<GUID>', depotPath: '//<myapp>/trunk'
}
```

and that should work, but it doesn't. What I've found is that it will work on the first attempt, during which it successfully checks out the code, but that every subsequent attempt fails with:

```
p4 reconcile -n -a -e -d -l -f C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test/...

P4 Task: attempt: 1
P4 Task: failed: com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: P4 Task: failed: com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException
Finished: FAILURE
```

The first challenge was that every run failed with a Java heap error. After half a day of bashing away I seem to have moved past that. I've since spent over a day trying every incarnation of p4sync that I could think of. The docs vary between attrocious and non-existent. I've spent ages in the DSL reference, tried many variations on adding additional arguments, spent hours searching the net gleaning snippets of information fron anywhere I could, and still no progress. I can't find a clear example of the syntax required for adding additional arguments. The snippet generator is missing options for almost every parameter in the normal GUI and what's there is unclear. I even tried reverting to the old perforce plug-in, which I later found Cloudbees' docs say isn't supported. After many. many trials and errors I've reverted to the simple version shown above based on info. found in a Cloudbees presentation. It hasn't helped.

I'm hoping that someone has this working and can provide a solid example.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I wonder if anyone ever solved it...

Comment: No, but this question is years old and it stopped in later versions. I should also note that syntax has changed over the years so I'd recommend the latest plugin and using the step generator to create the code.

Comment: Yeah I hadn't ran into it until yesterday. I'm getting this same behavior during a multi-branch pipeline sync on the latest jenkins LTS with the latest version of P4Plugin. I'll work it out :)